flutter emulator doesnt show code output, rather it opens up to show home screen
I have an emulator downloaded from android studio for flutter but when I run the code it doesnt show me the output but shows the home screen . i have tried redownloading it but it doesnt help, how can I solve this issue? Also my flutter runs completely fine
i tried redownloading it, doesnt help, cant understand what to do as im a newbiw
